# Any simple python package providing dict merge?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to do something like this:

```
merge({'a': 1}, {'b': 2})
```

and get a return of `{'a': 1, 'b':2}`.

1. I don't want to use `.update()`, which sadly doesn't return the updated or a new `dict`, just `None` (why?.....).
2. Since I know `.update()`, I could write a 3 line function for this. I don't, I just want an already existing/known package that do this kind of job in a simple way.

#### EDIT

This edit is just to explain the lovely SO users that this is not a duplicate of [How to merge two Python dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38987/1000282) and hence the chosen answer is unrelated with any of the answers provided in the candidate duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I merge two Python dictionaries in a single expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Comment: Not a duplicate. This one is asking for **packages that do this**, since it's not much native of python 2. Candidate duplicate is not looking for this aspect, and not providing answers in this sense.

Comment: @pepper_chico. So your question is actually [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), since you're asking people to recommend a software library.

Comment: You want to introduce a dependency for *this*?

Comment: @user2357112 yes!!, this act make it clear how nice this language is.

Comment: @ekhumoro if asking for a package that implements a given feature (not asking whether it's good or not and general recommendations) were to be deleted as off-topic this site would be bordering uselessness.

Comment: @pepper_chico. The help topic I linked to is pretty clear about what's off topic and why (see item four). There's also a [software recommendations SE site](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) which may be more suitable for this kind of question.

Comment: @ekhumoro didn't know of this SE site, first time seeing it. If I could, I'd migrate this question including answers there. Dunno whether SO (and SE in general) supports this.

Comment: @ekhumoro If there's no real migrating besides asking again there, better to leave it here since it's already answered.

Comment: @pepper_chico. Well, you seem to get the answer you were looking for, so it's probably best to just leave it here (but closed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package [`dictmerge`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dictmerge) can merge dictionaries.

As of Python 3.5 you can merge dictionaries without an additional package:

```
>>> d1 = {'a': 1}
>>> d2 = {'b': 2}
>>> {**d1, **d2}
{'b': 2, 'a': 1}
```

Comment: do you know whether this package doesn't suffer from slower perf like referred in http://stackoverflow.com/a/26853961/1000282?

Comment: @pepper_chico: I haven't measured it but it doesn't make unnecessary copies (implementation is fairly short as well): https://github.com/nvie/dictmerge/blob/master/dictmerge.py

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2.7, you can one-line (ignoring imports) a merge with:

```
from itertools import chain

merged = dict(chain(dict1.viewitems(), dict2.viewitems()))
```

In Py3.5 and higher, you can use [additional unpacking generalizations to do this without any functions at all](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/):

```
merged = {**dict1, **dict2}
```

The reason `dict.update` returns `None` is because Python methods, as a general rule, stick to *either* mutating an existing object *or* returning a new object, not both. Basically, functions with side-effects aren't supposed to be used in a functional manner (because it's liable to confuse).

Comment: I realize the why, the "why" was more rethorical than truthful. IMO, this is just not to confuse newbies, at the expense of usability, hence ".......".

Answer (score 0):

```
d1 = {'a': 1}
d2 = {'b': 2}

d3 = dict(d1, **d2)
```

As ShadowRanger points out in the comments, this only works if all keys of d2 are of type str.

Comment: downvoted, check this for why: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26853961/1000282

Comment: This is only legal if `d2` has purely `str` keys; otherwise, abusing keyword argument unpacking isn't legal for this purpose.

Comment: @ShadowRanger yep, upvoted your comment so people see it!

Comment: @Alex Comments are ephemeral. If you really want to highlight it, add it to your answer.